# Using iloc to find cells for calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, `df7`, which in part looks like this:

```
      ticker   obs_date  eps_median_est
448    HTHT 2018-07-27           0.240
449    HTHT 2018-08-15           0.170
261    TEAM 2018-07-26           0.010
262    TEAM 2018-08-19          -0.015
```

My goal is to subtract the second most recent esp_median_est from the most recent one.  For example in HTHT:  .17 - .24 =  -.07

There are two rows for each 'ticker'.

Here's what I have so far:

```
for each in symbol_list[0:]:
df8 = df7.loc[df7.ticker == each]
df8 = df8.tail(2)

df9.eps_chg  = (( df8.iloc[1,2] -  df8.iloc[0,2] ) / df8.iloc[1,2] ) *100
df10 = pd.concat([df10,df9],sort=False)
```

The error is IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what's wrong with df.groupby('ticker').diff()?

Comment: @Yuca OP asked for just the difference of the two most recent `eps_median_est`. `diff` will compute all differences. Also it produces `NaN` at the boundaries.

Comment: dropna fixes the nan issues, guess the real issue is to take only the two most recent, guess a `pd.head(4)` would do

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupby` ticker and subtract the `tail(1)` from `head(1)` to get the difference between first and last entries.

```
df7.groupby('ticker').eps_median_est.apply(lambda x: x.head(1).item() - x.tail(1).item())

ticker
HTHT    0.070
TEAM    0.025
Name: eps_median_est, dtype: float64
```

If you want the difference between the last two values, can do `tail(2)` and `diff()`

```
df.groupby('ticker').eps_median_est.apply(lambda x: x.tail(2).diff().dropna().item())

ticker
HTHT   -0.070
TEAM   -0.025
Name: eps_median_est, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do

```
df7.groupby('ticker')['eps_median_est'].apply(lambda g: g.iloc[-1] - g.iloc[-2])
```

Comment: What python sequence type does this output?  How to change it to a pandas DataFrame?